# just_audio seamless looping broken / clipping on iOS 17 flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, just-audio, ios17

we are using just_audio to handle the audio of our flutter app.

On devices running iOS 17+ the seamless looping does not work as intended, instead there is a jarring clipping noise between each loop. This issue did not appear after an update on our end, only after an iOS update.

This is highly disturbing to our app experience, as we are looping short audio files with the effect of creating a calming, relaxing environment for our users.

All works fine on android devices and iOS devices running iOS 15.5, any help is greatly appreciated.

Below is the code responsible for playing (and looping) the audio files:

```
 @override

   playMusic() async {
      Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  
      await audioPlayer.setFilePath("${appDocDir.path}/${frequency.audio_url}");
      
       
       await audioPlayer.setLoopMode(LoopMode.one);
       await audioPlayer.play();
       await audioPlayer.setVolume(audioVolume);
    
  }
```

You may test the app yourself using the following link: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/frequencies/id1622375454

Does anyone else have this problem?

Many thanks,

Declan